# Does Asus motherboard z170 Progaming support virtualization

Tags: motherboard

I went through complete specification for Asus 170 pro gaming motherboard, but I cannot see anywhere on their website whether it supports virtualization or not. I even talked on their support, but they to do not have this info.

So can anybody please guide me where I can confirm whether does it support virtualization?

Also does i7 6700 6th generation processor support virtualization?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. Have a look at [pg.67 \ section 2.6 of the user manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/972232/Asus-Z170-Pro-Gaming.html?page=67&term=virtualization#) (search for it online if link breaks).

> Active Processor Cores [All]
>
> This item allows you to select the number of CPU cores to activate in each processorpackage. Configuration options: [All](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/972232/Asus-Z170-Pro-Gaming.html?page=67&term=virtualization#) [2] [3]
>
> **Intel Virtualization Technology [Enabled]**
>   When set to [Enabled], a VMM can utilize the additional hardware capabilities provided byVanderpool Technology. Configuration options: [Disabled]
>
> [Enabled]Hardware Prefetcher [Enabled]
>
> This item allows the CPU to ...

Answer (score 0):

The ,'Z170 PRO Gaming' Motherboard and i7 6700 6th generation processor supports virtualization

To enable go to your BIOS, or 'UEFI BIOS Utility' in advanced option to enable (it should be in CPU Configuration depending on hardware and BIOS Version)

Here's a list of [6th gen i7 processors](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/88392/6th-generation-intel-core-i7-processors.html)

This is the [i7 processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88196/intel-core-i7-6700-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html) you were asking about, you can check that it supports virtualization under 'Advanced Technologies' and look at the sections labeled 'virtualization technology'

Here you can look up product specifications of all the intel processors to check for yourself
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html#@Processors

you can see if your processor is supported by checking the processor brand > generation , model > and then look under 'advanced technologies' in 'specifications'

Example:
'Intel Core Processors' > '7th generation i3' > 'i3-7300' > 'Advanced Technologies'

You can also download the '[Intel Processor Identification Utility](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005651/processors.html)' to determine if virtualization is supported if in 'CPU Technologies' after its complete